# Tracking usage of applications during the day

Tags: logging, time-management

*I know such applications exist, but I'm not sure how they're really called. If someone could just direct me to a link to a similar question, that'd be fine.*

Anyways, I'm looking for an application, that monitors how much during the day, was each application used. The problem is that some of them (firefox playing radio, visual studio always open ...) are running all the time - so I would need something to measure time during which it was actively used (for example, if firefox is running, but no mouse clicks or keyboard ticks, then put it in "passive" mode).

Is something like that available ?

Appreciate all advice on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) is one such.
[FriutfulTime](http://www.fruitfultime.com/) is another.
There is an OSX app called [Slife](http://www.slifelabs.com/).

Answer (score 6):

Not one I've used, but I've heard a lot of good things about [TimeSnapper](http://timesnapper.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I've only briefly used it, but [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com/) seems to cover everything you're after.

Answer (score 1):

[Wakoopa](http://wakoopa.com/) is a nice application that will track which applications you are using.

Answer (score 0):

[Whatpulse](http://whatpulse.org) supports application tracking (active and passive) in OSX and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

My own app [Timing](https://timingapp.com/) (see the screenshot below) does this for macOS. It automatically tracks which documents you edit and which websites you visit, so that you can later review what exactly you have done. You can also manually add offline activities so that they don't get lost. All data is stored locally and there is no subscription required.

[image: Screenshot of Timing for Mac]