# Tool to capture screen at regular intervals

Tags: windows-xp, screenshot, screen-capture

I want a tool that can take screenshots of my screen at regular intervals and save the images in a folder. Is there any tool?

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: Windows XP OS .

Comment: related? http://superuser.com/questions/50112/tracking-usage-of-applications-during-the-day http://superuser.com/questions/917/time-tracking-applications

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/148188/program-that-does-a-screen-print-every-15-minutes-and-saves-it-to-a-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with [`picpick`](http://picpick.wiziple.net) you can:

- autosave pictures into a folder of your choice
- take snapshots via commandline like `picpick.exe /cf` (which then stores the picture to the folder you have defined

combine that with the regular task scheduling of windows and you got what you want.