# Program that does a screen print every 15 minutes and saves it to a file

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture

I remember hearing of some software that would take a screen print every 15 minutes and store it in a file. They mentioned it can be used to keep track of the amount of time you spent on a project.

I know of SnagIt. http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp

What are some of the other packages out there?

Comment: Yes, there is a TON of software available to do this kind of activity.

Comment: Yea, and a lot of it will install itself, given the opportunity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[TimeSnapper](http://www.timesnapper.com/):

> The Automatic Screenshot Journal
>
> TimeSnapper runs in the background of
>   your computer, taking screenshots of
>   your desktop every few seconds all
>   week long.
>
> Where did all my time go?TimeSnapper lets you
>   play back your week just like a movie.
>   You can play it at any speed you like,
>   and jump in at any time you like.
>
> When it's time to fill out that
>   dreaded timesheet, TimeSnapper is a
>   savior. No need to tear your hair out
>   trying to remember where all the time
>   went.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't specified operating system so on linux I'd add this to my crontab:

```
*/15 * * * * scrot
```

Assuming scrot was installed.

Comment: Have you tested it? Does it work? I could imagine that the `DISPLAY` variable won't be correctly set from within a crontab. Changing `scrot` to `DISPLAY=:0 scrot` or something similar might be needed. If you have tested it and it works, don't mind me :-) .

Comment: Instead of crontab, a quick-and-dirty one-liner in a minimized console did the trick for me: `while [ 1 ]; do scrot -z -d 900; done`.

Answer (score 4):

[AutoScreenShot](http://www.theuds.com/autoscreenshot.php?lang=EN):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One of the so many software that can do that.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Capture/Automatic-Print-Screen-With-Email.shtml

Answer (score 2):

TimeSnapper and Irfanview are nice, but they are missing a key feature: **stop capturing when the computer is locked**. It's pretty annoying to have thousands of screenshots of "Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to login". Using the free [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) tool from Task Scheduler can resolve that. You need to create two tasks:

**Screen Capture Task**

- *Triggers*

  - `At logon`
  - `On workstation unlock`
- *Actions (assuming a screenshot every 5 minutes)*

  - `nircmd execmd md C:\Snapshots\~$currdate.yyyy.MM.dd$`
  - `nircmd loop -1 300000 savescreenshot C:\Snapshots\~$currdate.yyyy.MM.dd$\~$currdate.yyyy.MM.dd$-~$currtime.HH_mm_ss$.png`

**Screen Capture - Stop on Unlock**

- *Trigger:* `On workstation unlock`
- *Action:* `taskkill /IM nircmd.exe /F`

It's not perfect because if you have `NirCmd` running in the background for other reasons, the "Stop on Unlock" task might kill it instead, but I reckon this won't be the case for the vast majority of users.

Answer (score 1):

REFOG is one that is free, and it has the ability to record anything else