# AutoSnapshot every minute?

Tags: windows, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program that does a screen print every 15 minutes and saves it to a file](https://superuser.com/questions/148188/program-that-does-a-screen-print-every-15-minutes-and-saves-it-to-a-file)

What app can i use to take screenshots of my full screen automatically every minute or so? I should be able to have this start automatically and there should be no signs (so i dont get distracted).

For Windows XP

Comment: Moderator please merge this post with the another one. A notable point in his question is it should leave no signs. There is a software like that but its a hacking tool used as key logger so is it legible to put the download link to that software here

Comment: Keyloggers are probably much more effective. Just sayin.

Comment: If by "no signs" he means nothing in the system tray, then I'd agree this may warrant its own question.

Comment: system tray is fine but not preferred. Keyloggers? the hell, no i need to see my progress throughout the day or session :p. I'll agree that a keylogger is much more of a hacking tool :p

Comment: Well then Timesnapper in the other answer is a good suggestion.  I use it. (classic, the free one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AutoScreenShot](http://www.theuds.com/autoscreenshot.php?lang=EN) can do it. It's freeware.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Download [Automatically Take Screenshots](http://www.sobolsoft.com/autoscreenshot/). An advantage I found was you can check  the "Load this software on Windows startup" which will automatic launch the application during windows start up and the application goes to the system tray during startup.

[image]

Comment: tried this today. i have to say if you use the free versions it's utterly pointless, because it opens a box you have to click away after each screenshot. if you dont click it away it wont take another screenshot, no matter the settings.