# Windows fire-and-forget screen capturing software?

Tags: windows, automation, screenshot

I need a Windows tool that can be configured to auto-start and auto-screenshot a window (ideally a certain window only).

It should not require any user interaction other than initial configuration. It should be capable of making a capture every few seconds and save it to disk.

This is for a legacy software running on a crammed-away desktop machine (don't ask…) whose main window displays the status of some equipment. This should be published to our Intranet in form of a screenshot so people do no longer need to remote into the machine every time they need to check the status the software displays.

Most of the screen shot tools/suites I've seen so far do not seem to be able to fulfill the main requirement: auto-start and don't ask any questions.

Comment: Elite key logger can do most of this as well.

Comment: @aking1012: I'm not seeking to spy on anyone, and I have a strong suspicion my employer would disapprove of installing a keylogger on corporate hardware.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/148188/program-that-does-a-screen-print-every-15-minutes-and-saves-it-to-a-file/

Comment: My pleasure....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Irfanview.com](http://www.irfanview.com) . It has a command line mode with switches that you could trigger from other app (or any script, vb application, even dos batch) , or launch directly. It has an automatic mode/screensaver like mode.  It has an advanced capturing system allowing:

- command line mode available
- capture every x amount of seconds you set. (and can be triggered from command line mode)
- capture per key stroke
- include mouse cursor if wished
- capture full desktop
- capture only active windows
- capture active windows only client area
- capture custom rectangle region
- capture per object clicked
- scroll to capture off screen content
- captured data go to irfanview screen, or direct to disk in the any of the many formats it has, and with the settings per format you wish. Possibility to use a special language of tags for naming.
- very advanced batch processing with filters and editing operations.
- much more.
- it's freeware.

I am not affiliated with it in any way, just love the tool, is my main viewer/converter :)

Comment: Okay. Works well enough with a scheduled task. Now here's the complication: I get a blank screenshot when the workstation is locked (naturally, when you think of it). I expect it that there is no way to capture a window when the machine is locked or the screensaver is active... Or is there?

Comment: Maybe an rdp session and disabling the screensaver, then screenshotting that or forcing a new remote login as a scheduled task do disable the screensaver?

Comment: @aking1012: Yeah, I've disabled the screen saver locally. I don't think there is a way to do screen captures on a locked machine. I can work with irfanview at that stage and it's enough for the purpose.