# timed desktop screenshot for timelapse

Tags: windows, open-source, screenshot, screen-capture

I've been looking around for a screen capture program that gives me actual images of the desktop, and allows me to take them on a certain interval so that I can combine them into a timelapse.

ex) Take a screenshot every 1000ms, save as .PNG

I've seen applications make desktop timelapses, but they are directly converted into compressed video formats, which isn't very useful for me.

An option to add timestamps at the bottom would be a plus.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to capture screen at regular intervals](http://superuser.com/questions/122799/tool-to-capture-screen-at-regular-intervals) or [Program that does a screen print every 15 minutes and saves it to a file](http://superuser.com/q/148188/13567)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking around for a long time I found some alternatives to this.

The best however, is a program called 'chronolapse', it has lots of options, is regularly updated and open source!

Check it out! http://keeyai.com/projects-and-releases/chronolapse/

Answer (score 2):

Chronolapse is your best bet. However I must caution you though that the quality is pretty bad sometimes since it doesn't support lossless formats like 32 bit bitmaps.

The problem is that the captured screenshots keep some of the pixels previously captured. The result is that the pixels is rather miscolored from time to time. Yes it's freeware, and it totally shows, since you get pretty much what you pay for.

Don't get me wrong. The tool is rock solid, however it sure needs some finetuning. The bug described above happens when you take frequent screenshots. I cannot tell how it handles less frequent screenshots though.