# Computer usage statistics from clients

Tags: windows, time-management

I want to get workers' computer usage report for many computers. For example: daily messenger usage is 3 hours, Photoshop usage 5 hours, etc.

Is there any program which has a centralized reporting system? I tried ExtraSpy but it is not working correctly because of being beta version.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/50112/tracking-usage-of-applications-during-the-day

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[Manic Time](http://www.manictime.com/)**.  Free and pro versions, the free version will do the job well.

[image]
I am not affiliated with the product in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: Yes this is what I need but I have 30 computers. I need a centralized database.

Comment: say that in your question then, @Baran...Can't think of anything else...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Worktime](http://www.nestersoft.com/worktime/for_company.shtml)

It's not free, but I think it provides the centralized DB that you want.