# How can I verify if virus threats are false positives or actually threats?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, virus-removal, avast

I was trying to install some time tracking applications: [Procrastitracker](http://strlen.com/procrastitracker/) and [Fruitful Time](https://www.fruitfultime.com/) based on suggestions from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/50112/tracking-usage-of-applications-during-the-day).

Unfortunately, Avast keeps showing me messages about `IDP.Alexa.51` and `IDP generic` in these apps respectively. Is there any way to know if such messages are false positives or if the file is actually harmful?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill I actually tried that after posting the questions and this is my result: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/2146d0825f920702b87e37e3653da2906dcd92dfd634e626f1a67fd817f8f5ba/detection

It says 3 engines detected this file. On my machine, Avast was showing the `IDP.generic` error but on Virus Total it said undetected. So, am I safe?

Comment: {shrug} no idea. It's not clear.

Comment: Its probably a false positive, but no guarantees. See https://www.2-spyware.com/remove-idp-alexa-51.html